# Как можно сделать портфолио в две строки по 3 столбца с переносами при изменении разрешения?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как можно сделать портфолио в две строки по 3 столбца с переносами при изменении разрешения?
Сделать адаптивным через флекс/грид?
Как на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="Project-block">
                                    <div class="block1">
                                        <img src="img/photo.png" alt=""><br>
                                        <span>Claritas Etiam Processus</span>
                                        <p>Photography, Nature</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="block1">
                                        <img src="img/photo1.png" alt=""><br>
                                        <span>Claritas Etiam Processus</span>
                                        <p>Photography, Nature</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="block1">
                                        <img src="img/photo2.png" alt=""><br>
                                        <span>Claritas Etiam Processus</span>
                                        <p>Photography, Nature</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="block1">
                                        <img src="img/photo3.png" alt=""><br>
                                        <span>Claritas Etiam Processus</span>
                                        <p>Photography, Nature</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="block1">
                                        <img src="img/photo4.png" alt=""><br>
                                        <span>Claritas Etiam Processus</span>
                                        <p>Photography, Nature</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="block1">
                                        <img src="img/photo5.png" alt=""><br>
                                        <span>Claritas Etiam Processus</span>
                                        <p>Photography, Nature</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: так https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/vQXeoN ?

Answer (score 0):

Через флексы, ставишь враперу стиль который написан ниже, и все будет как ты хочешь

.Project-block{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: Да,но надо чтобы оно при переносе становилось 3 строки по 2 блока а потом 6 строк по 1 блоку
При таком выполнении станет при сужении 2 строки по 4 и 2 блока, которые вторые будут по краям контейнера,а оно этстетически не очень)
По этому надо чтобы оно при переносе становилось 3 строки по 2 блока)